# Cygwin not detecting files that a Linux PC detects

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

So, I have a bash script on a Linux machine that compiles a bunch of videos for me, which is running an SFTP server using Linux Mint. I also have a Windows 10 PC which can encode much faster using CygWin (Better than Windows 10's bash), and can detect the SFTP drive through a program. I run the script and it states that the video files I want to encode don't exist, even though it does work on the Linux PC. I added this line to the script and it does change the root directory on CygWin.

```
rootdir='/cygdrive/x'
if [ ! -d "$rootdir" ];then rootdir='';fi
```

The file names I want to encode have spaces in them, and I notice when I go to the directory where they're located and run `ls`, CygWin adds single quotes and escapes the filenames, while Bash on Linux Mint doesn't do that. What I want to do is be able to run the script on the Windows machine from Cygwin so I can encode the video much faster than the Linux machine, but am not sure how to get CygWin to properly detect files as a Linux PC would.

Here is some example code:

```
#!/bin/bash

cudr="`pwd`";rootdir='/cygdrive/x'
if [ ! -d "$rootdir" ];then rootdir='';fi

mkdir -p "op"
ffmpeg -i "$cudr/a dog.mp4" "$cudr/op/1.mp4"
ffmpeg -i "$cudr/the cat's fat.mp4" "$cudr/op/2.mp4"
```

This runs fine on the Linux PC, but when running in CygWin ffmpeg will state that the input file isn't found, even though it's there in ls but escaped.

Comment: Cygwin `ls` might be printing them with quotes, but that's just for you the human's benefit.  You shouldn't be parsing that `ls` output anyway, so if you show us your code and more about what you're trying to do we might be able to help.  (See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @EricRenouf I added example code.

Comment: @EricRenouf Cygwin's `ls` doesn't do that by default though, and there's nothing in his post that suggests he's parsing the output of `ls`. I suspect that the files names might have have extra single quotes in them. The original poster might want to use Windows Explorer or the `dir` command from the Windows command prompt to find out what names these files actually have.

Comment: @RossRidge I think the newest version of cygwin's `ls` does in fact do that by default, but I agree with the sample code now in there it doesn't look like that's the problem

Comment: If ffmpeg is not a cygwin program will not understand the "/" but expect "\" for directory levels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code may have been oversimplified.  As it currently stands, you can just use the implicit current directory and it's all relative.  (I also removed `$rootdir` since you don't use it):

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p "op"
ffmpeg -i "a dog.mp4" "op/1.mp4"
ffmpeg -i "the cat's fat.mp4" "op/2.mp4"
```

Also note that the present working directory, which is returned by the `pwd` command, is also stored as `$PWD`, so you don't need to assign it unless you'll be changing directories and you want to remember the original.

Assuming there's more to your code than what you've shown and that you *do* need absolute paths, I believe you want to use [cygpath](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html).  My Cygwin-fu is very rusty, but I think you want something like this:

```
mkdir -p "op"
ffmpeg -i "$(cygpath -w "$cudr/a dog.mp4")" "$(cygpath -w "$cudr/op/1.mp4")"
ffmpeg -i "$(cygpath -w "$cudr/the cat's fat.mp4")" "$(cygpath -w "$cudr/op/2.mp4")"
```

(Never mind that the syntax highlighting messes up on that.  The shell understands that the quotes inside `$(…)` command substitutions differ from the quotes outside it, so you can nest one deep.)

Comment: I had just used the variable as an example, as in the real code the files are actually placed in a different directory than the script. The rootdir was there also to identify the root of the remote machine from inside cygwin.

Comment: That makes sense and was anticipated.  Does `"$(cygpath -w "$blah")"` work for you?